# error finding ros controll in catkin_make

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was following ros control tutorial to control robot in gazebo with ros, but as i try to build the package by running catkin_make i get this error:

```
-- Could not find the required component 'ros_control'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
  any of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ros_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  myrobot_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

my CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myrobot_control)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ros_control
  ros_controllers
)
    catkin_package()
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

I have installed ros-control package by sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control but it didn't helped.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14247/error-finding-ros-controll-in-catkin_make/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok problem, solved i have to install 2 extra packages which is not mentioned in the documentation also, and these are:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-effort-controllers
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joint-state-controller
```

---

Originally posted by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) with karma: 56 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0